# How to remove all duplicates from list except one element in Python?

Tags: python, performance, list

I already know how to remove all duplicates from `List` by using `set`:

```
ls = list(set(ls))
```

What i want to know is there any way to remove all duplicates except one element instances, as efficient as the method above?

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
#i want to keep 4, no matter if it is duplicate but want to remove duplicates from rest
so the output should be:
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

One possible solution is to iterate over element and use conditional check. I am looking for the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to add back in the extra deleted `4`s:

```
sl = list(set(ls))
sl += [4] * (ls.count(4) - 1)
```

Alternatively, just always append the `4`s to the new list:

```
s = set()
sl = []
for elem in ls:
    if elem == 4 or elem not in s:
        sl.append(elem)
        s.add(elem)
```

Using a `set` allows constant time membership testing; if you just used lists it would be  O(n).

You can write it as a list comprehension if you want, but the normal loop is more readable:

```
s = set()
sl = [s.add(elem) or elem for elem in ls if elem == 4 or elem not in s]
```